# How to send message to workgroup using PHP and CMD command?

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, xampp

I want to send a message to another PC in my workgroup.

I use Windows 7 Professional and Xampp server.

I use this code:

```
<?php
echo exec('C:\windows\system32\msg PCuser massage');
?>
```

But this is not working. So I tried another method like this:

```
<?php
echo exec('d:\test.bat');
?>
```

`test.bat` contains:

```
msg user 1
```

I open `test.bat` file and set it to run as admin so it will go straight to `C:\windows\system32`, and excecute the command.

But I get error message:

**"C:\Windows\msg.exe is not a valid Win32 application"**

But when I try to double click the .bat file, the pop up shows normally.

I want make a PHP form that can send a message to another computer like this:

PC name: **____**

Massage: **____**

```
<?php
$PCname=Input Post PC name;
$message=Input Post message;
echo exec('C:\windows\system32\msg'.$PCname.$message);
?>
```

So I can input the message and send then to specified PC.

**UPDATE**

I know I can run `msg` command without `C:\windows\system32`, but I still have the error message when I do this:

```
<?php
exec('msg user 1');
?>
```

I get again this error:

**"C:\Windows\msg.exe is not a valid Win32 application"**

I use `href` in my html to link to `test.bat` file and when I click on this hyperlink, I can download my `test.bat` file. When I click next to run it, then I get same error. I close my browser open my download folder and open `test.bat` file by double click and it runs normally.

So here are the questions:

1. Can I run `msg` command in PHP or in browser?
2. What is an alternate to do that? Which program can I use to run `msg` command?

Comment: `exec` expects an executable as its first argument. a batch file is NOT an executable. you have to exec `cmd.exe /c test.bat`.

Comment: To execute a command as administrator on Windows, your apache has to be running under admin user.

Comment: i do this in my php exec ('cmd.exe /c d:\test.bat'); and run my xampp with administrator still same